# Rereturn dataset that contains multiple tables asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

I am executing 3 select queries,now i want to store the result of 3 different queries in different tables of dataset,so that i can display different tables in different gridviews,but i am getting index out of range exception,below is my code-

public DataSet viewdeal1()

```
    {
        //string connectionString = "Data Source=INGNRILPSQL02;Initial Catalog=AHD08_A40;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=a36;Password=a36";
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=DELL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Nikita;Integrated Security=True";

        string queryString3 = "Select PS3_Dealer.DealerID,DealerName,ContactNo,NoOfVehicles,CommittedDate from PS3_Dealer where CommittedDate<GETDATE()";



        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(queryString3, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sc);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        // sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da.Fill(ds.Tables[0]);

        string queryString1 = "Select PS3_Dealer.DealerID,DealerName,ContactNo,NoOfVehicles,CommittedDate from PS3_Dealer inner join (select DealerID from PS3_Vehicle inner join PS3_VehicleBooking on PS3_Vehicle.VehicleID!=PS3_VehicleBooking.VehicleID) as H on PS3_Dealer.DealerID=H.DealerID";
        SqlCommand sc1 = new SqlCommand(queryString1, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sc1);

        // sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da1.Fill(ds.Tables[1]);


        string queryString2 = "Select PS3_Dealer.DealerID,DealerName,ContactNo,NoOfVehicles,CommittedDate from PS3_Dealer inner join (Select DealerID from PS3_Vehicle inner join PS3_VehicleBooking on PS3_Vehicle.VehicleID=PS3_VehicleBooking.VehicleID where EndDate< GETDATE()) as Q on PS3_Dealer.DealerID=Q.DealerID";

        SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand(queryString2, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(sc2);

        // sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da2.Fill(ds.Tables[2]);










        connection.Close();



        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: You probably need to declare each `DataTable` first, fill it, and then add it to the `DataSet`.  I.e., `DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(); da.Fill(dt1); ds.Tables.Add(dt1);` or something to that effect.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create the three (empty) DataTables when you create the DataSet:  `DataSet ds = new DataSet(); ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable()); ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable()); ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable());`. The point being that a newly created `DataSet` won't have any `DataTable`, so you're attempting to reference something that doesn't exist yet - hence the index out of range error.

Comment: Thanks,now i want to bind these tables with 3 different gridview on a page, so i should write like this in code behind file-"GridView1.DataSource = fg.Tables[0];GridView1.DataBind();" or there is other way?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.